check if given object implements certain generic interface; type argument(s) NOT known
I have some object. I want to check at runtime if it is an IReadOnlyCollection<T> of any T, i.e. I cannot specify that T in my check. So it should return true for e.g. IReadOnlyCollection<string>, IImmutableSet<int> and IImmutableList<object> but false for e.g. IList<int[]> and string.
I have tried
public bool isReadOnlyCollection(object o)
{
    return typeof(IReadOnlyCollection<>).IsAssignableFrom(o.GetType())
}

but this returns false for above cases. It does return true if I give a type argument, i.e. return typeof(IReadOnlyCollection<int>).IsAssignableFrom(o.GetType()) and o has according type argument. But I cannot give a type argument because it can be anything at runtime.
